# end_request: I/O error on external drive

Tags: 11.10, usb-drive

I've been seeing occasional errors like this:

```
kernel: [786407.826017] end_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 1424776960
```

sdd is a 1GB external seagate drive, split into a 600 MB ext2 (sdd2) and a 400 MB NTFS (sdd1).

Is this error due to the fact that the drive auto-powers off, or is it time to budget for a replacement?

I did not see any errors like this prior to upgrading from 10.04 to 11.10.

Comment: The surrounding lines in the log should provide a bit more information.

Comment: There's nothing else - just the single line.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the SMART disk status and run the long self test with the disk utility.  That should tell you if you need to replace the drive.

Comment: I don't think you can access the SMART parameters from a USB drive.

Comment: @chris, then you might fall back to the old and dumb `badblocks` command.